# error `conditional binary operator expected` in compound branch

Tags: bash

I am running such a program:

```
    min_val=1
    max_val=100
    int=50  
    if [[ "$int" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        if [[ "$int" -ge "$min_val" && -le "$max_val" ]]; then
            echo "$int is within $min_val to $max_val."
        else
            echo "$int is out of range."
        fi
    else
        echo "int is not an integer." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
```

It  report error

```
    $ bash test_integer3.sh
    test_integer3.sh: line 12: conditional binary operator expectedtest_integer3.sh: 
    line 12: syntax error near `"$max_val"'test_integer3.sh: 
    line 12: `    if [[ "$int" -ge "$min_val" && -le "$max_val" ]]; then'
```

I have examined carefully line-by-line.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if [[ "$int" -ge "$min_val" && -le "$max_val" ]]; then
```

You will have to compare against `$int` in both comparisons:

```
if [[ "$int" -ge "$min_val" ]] && [[ "$int" -le "$max_val" ]]; then
```

or,

```
if (( int >= min_val )) && (( int <= max_val )); then
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `-le` doesn't have a left operand.